# Could this relay be controlled directly with GPIO pin?

Tags: gpio, relay

Can be [this relay](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/262/datasheet_reed_relay_SIL-773725.pdf) and more precisely SIL03-1A72-71D variant controlled directly from RPi?

The data sheet specifies coil resistance of 500 Ohm which at 3.3 V voltage gives 6.6 mA control current, which is well within 16 mA limit.

Am I correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the datasheet I come to the same conclusion. It should work. Driving this relay from digital logic interface seems to be the intended use case.

I am however not clear if the [flyback diode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyback_diode) is included for this particular model or if it is optionally. If it is not allready include you must provide it externally otherwise damaging the GPIO pin is indeed a real danger.

Comment: Does it include a flyback diode internally?  I didn't understand what the datasheet was saying.

Comment: That is indeed a question that came to me too, @joan.

Comment: Those relays come in a lot of different types and options. There are versions with and without internal flyback diode.

Comment: From other data sheets of this manufacurer I learned that the last 'D' happen to mean "diode", but I won't leave it to the chance of course, and verify that by testing it with power supply. The only bothers me, how I know where is pin 1. Put it wrong way - RPi will be destroyed by short curcuit to ground, before it gets the chance to be destroyed by EMF...

Comment: @AndreyPro there's a notch in the package to indicate the orientation (presumably pin 1 though the datasheet is not clear about that). If you have the model with integrated diode the pin numbering can be easily verified.